# trying to add bones to my character model but its too laggy

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

hey everyone so I am trying to add bones to my character model , but when I try to press ctrl j to join all all together it just wont work , it will freeze and than crash , I Might add my character to mixamo so it can automatically add bones , but unfortunately Its just I cant export it , maybe its just too much veritcies , I will add a blend file because Its better details , thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: You have all the subdiv modifier viewport levels set to 4 which is far too high while the render levels are set to 2. If you reduce them all to 2 you'll get rid of any lag. Not had time to look at the rest of the model yet, but that might be why joining your model is crashing Blender. - You'll also need to convert all your Bezier curves to meshes before joining them.

Comment: i actually did it and it worked thank you actually , if u can see my last comment below , i could get a help also , thank you

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: yeah i did thank you , but how do export it to mixamo with colors ? sometimes i do this but exported without colors just white

Comment: Assuming you're exporting in fbx file format, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different modifiers are assigned to different parts of this model. If you want to merge the model into one object you will need to apply these modifiers first.

Comment: thank you so much it worked , last question if i wanna export it do mixamo , what option should i pick to make the colors appear in the mixamo , thank you